# Android Ads are not showing in Google Pixel 2 XL

Tags: android

I have implemented the rewarded ads video according to the documentation and guide mentioned in this link
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-rewarded-video-android/index.html#0

But, it gives following error in GOOGLE PIXEL 2 XL Device

> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>       com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.source.ae: None of the available extractors (n, g) could read the stream.
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.source.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207000@21207000.283464268.283464268:6)
>           at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.upstream.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@21207000@21207000.283464268.283464268:6)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

Comment: Is the error only happening on the Pixel phone and other phones work fine? What Android version is running on the Pixel phone?

Comment: yes, this is happening only in Pixel 2XL and it is android10. Although, in other android10 devices like realme3 pro .. ads are working fine

Comment: @Nico please help me

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not able to help at this particular problem. I just asked those questions for future viewers to have some important informations about this problem.